# Vector of custom class contained pointer of other class

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a short code with vector which element are custom class objects.
The custom class also contained a pointer to another class.
The memory of b_ptr were freed after delete aPtr in main process cause it only copy the pointer(not stored data) when push_back object to vector.
Any idea to solve this? 
(*shared_ptr is not able to use in my system.)

Thanks~

```
struct myStruct
{
  vector<uint16_t> pers;
  vector<string>   strs;
};

class A
{
  A(){ b_ptr = new B() };      
  B* b_ptr;
};

class B
{
  B();
  vector<myStruct> mStruct;
};
```

And main process as below

```
main()
{
  vector<A> v_of_a;
  A* aPtr;

  while(something != NULL)
  {
    aPtr = new A();
    //Handling with data for property of A, vector data of B
    v_of_a.push_back(*aPtr);
    delete aPtr;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I am confused, delete aPtr should delete everything associated with the object created for the A object.  Are you wanting to keep a reference to b_ptr around somewhere in memory?  Are you wanting to copy this to memory somewhere, is that what you are saying?

Comment: I've done my best, but it's really not clear what you're asking here. Please revise your question with a clear explanation of (1) what you are trying to do (2) how you are trying to do it (3) what happens (4) what you expect to happen

Comment: I delete aPtr because it's content copied to a new element of vector when push_back it into vector, isn't it? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: Sorry for not make my question clear~
I am trying to do store data (created in aPtr) in vector. 
New a A object and push_back to vector (as I know it should a new element to store data).
After push_back, release aPtr and new a A object for next data.

Vector copied the pointer value (address of B object) not content of B, so the address of B that stored in vector will be invalid after I delete aPtr.

So I would like to ask for a better way to solve this. 
Maybe not declare a pointer of B in A, instead of declare a B instance?

Comment: I suddenly understood I should push_back the address of aPtr into the vector and not delete aPtr. Then free the memory of the A object that aPtr point to via free vector when program going to exit.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking "how do I get the memory pointed to by b_ptr to be deallocated when the A instance is?

To do this, you need to use a destructor:

```
struct A {
    A() {
        b_ptr = new B();
    }

    ~A() {
        delete b_ptr;
    }

    B* b_ptr;
};
```

Comment: You should edit this to properly follow the rule of five. As is, this would create dangling pointers and double deletes.

Comment: It would also over complicate the answer and is beside the point.